# Will I be charged if I give the credit card information but then not verify the account. (Google Cloud Platform)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I just signed up for a free trial in Google Cloud but then after giving billing info, I changed my mind and then did not want the Service to charge me money, so I did not verify my account. After signing in to the billing service it was written that my billing account is closed and suspended until I verify my account, if I never verify it, would I never be charged?
And, I am not going to use Google Cloud Platform anytime in the future.

Comment: There are three accounts to be aware of. Google Payments Account, Google Billing Account, and the Google Cloud Projects. Your credit card is attached to the Google Payments Account. @DazWilkin answered about being charged. Provided that you do not use any services beyond the free trial and the initial credit you will not be charged except for a refunded initial payment card charge of about $1.00. If you will not be using Google services, delete all three accounts. You can create new accounts at a later date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **should** not be billed.

Verification is Google's way of confirming that you're a legitimate user of the credit card. If it can't verify you, it can't prove that it will get paid by your credit card company and thus, it shouldn't bill you.

In the unlikely event that it does bill you, I think (!) you couldn't be held liable for any charges and could contest the charge with your credit card company.